# C++ Pointer object lost outside of function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers, methods, reference

I have created an object of a certain class. The class is "Node" and it has an attribute of `CString strName`. The value of this variable can be retrieved with a method of Node: `CString Node::GetName()`, which just returns the name of the variable.

In the following method I instantiate this:

```
Node* UpperClass::GetObject(CString value) {
    Node retObject;
    retObject.strName = value;

    Trace(retObject.strName); // Prints argument to trace file - this prints the value of strName fine

    return &retObject;
}
```

Then I run this method in a second class:

```
Node* LowerClass::Get() {
    Node *pReturn = instanceOfUpperClass.GetObject();

    Trace(pReturn->GetName()); // This trace just prints blank...

    return *(&pReturn);
}
```

As you can see by the code comments, it seems to lose the value when it is passed to the second method. I've attempted to research this but am having some real trouble getting to grips with why.. can anyone help?

As an aside, if one is wondering about the return value of the second method, I am intending to past the resultant pointer to a third function where I utilise it for processing (messy, I know, but I inherited the code and have no choice); just in case that has any bearing on the answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `retObject` is a local variable(automatic variable) and it's lifetimes does not extend beyond `GetObject`, trying to refer to that memory after the method returns is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

int this method:

```
Node* UpperClass::GetObject(CString value) {
    Node retObject;
    retObject.strName = value;

    Trace(retObject.strName); // Prints argument to trace file - this prints the value of strName fine

    return &retObject; // <-- Undefined Baaviour
}
```

you are returning pointer to local object, which is destroyed once this method ends. You should create retObject dynamically, and return pointer to it, or better put this pointer into shared_ptr<>.

Comment: Ah I see, I thought that was just an inherent difference with pointers, but the trick is to use dynamically-allocated memory! That's also let me get rid of that horrible return value as the third method works fine too.. It all makes sense. I will just have to remember to free the memory once I've finished with it... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `Node retObject` is a local variable when you go out of scope of the function `GetObject` any use of the object is undefined.  And in this case you return a pointer to that object.

Comment: Right so even though the pointer seems to move fine the object itself has gone out of scope.. makes sense now. Cheers!